# Test Angular 2 component in ES5?

Tags: angular

I'm starting a new Angular 2 application. I have a simple component that is essentially a dropdown select box. The component takes a few objects as properties (in the app, through attributes on the component's DOM element in the containing templates).

The official docs for Angular 2 don't have examples of testing components yet. How would I test the actual view of the component--check that appropriate DOM elements are created based on data being set on the component?

I can create one of my components by doing `ng.core.Injector.resolveAndCreate([...dependencies...]).get(MyClassName)`. But that doesn't actually construct the view, or let me pass in data to be set as the properties of the component I just created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following what you see in the docs and the repo source code is not that difficult. Here's the setup I made and it works.

First from the docs I took jasmine example setup

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
<script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
```

Then angular2's setup. You may already know that when you write in ES5 you must use UMD bundles

```js
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all-testing.umd.dev.js"></script>
```

Now the important part, the testing. The main task here is create a Test Component

```js
var TestComponent = ng.core.
    Component({
        selector: 'cmp',
        template : '' // Left it blank, we override it when testing
    }).Class({
        constructor: function() {
            this.someProperty = 'Initial value';
        }
    });
```

After creating the component, you can test it by using TestComponentBuilder

```js
ng.testing.describe('Component building', function() {

    ng.testing.it('should detect when a property changes', 
        ng.testing.inject([ng.testing.TestComponentBuilder], function(tcb) {
            tcb
                .overrideTemplate(TestComponent, '<div>{{someProperty}}</div>')
                .createAsync(TestComponent)
                .then(function(fixture) {

                    // Triggers change detection so 
                    // the div actually contains the property value
                    fixture.detectChanges();

                    // Check if the div contains the correct value
                    expect(fixture.nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Initial value');

                    // Change property's value
                    fixture.componentInstance.someProperty = 'New value';

                    // Triggers change detection again
                    fixture.detectChanges();

                    // Check, again, if the div contains the new value
                    expect(fixture.nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('New value');
                });
        }));
});
```

*Note that I'm using `ng.testing.(describe/it/etc)` because those functions from jasmine were patched to work with angular2.*

From this point it will be super easy to continue. You already have the entire repo to see their [specs](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2/test). An interesting one is for [NgFor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/test/common/directives/ng_for_spec.ts). You can follow the TS/ES6 examples, they are the same.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnwCP6d06GMcHOzxRllt) with a repro working.

**Reference**

You can check as well Julie Ralph's [repo (ng2-test-seed)](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed) and her [talk at AngularConnect 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0F2E-PRm44)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's tremendously helpful! I'm not sure what docs you're talking about though, the "testing guides" at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/ don't have the sections on testing components, services, or DOM yet.

Comment: Sorry! I meant the part of setting up Jasmine (I took it from docs)! Glad it helped :)

Comment: Quick follow-on: Why is `overrideTemplate` required? When I remove it, the `.then(` never seems to be fired. How can I use my original component html template in testing?

Comment: You can use `template` property, I just got used to using `overrideTemplate` by following the official testing source code. Note that there is currently a bug when using `templateUrl` (check [#5662](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5662)).

Comment: Do you know how to add router config on Component with ES5?